# Upgrade MS Access 2010 Solution to Office 365 MS Access version

Tags: office365

We have an application where the front end is built on MS access vb.net code also we have MS access DB and Backend SQL DB. We are in the process of upgrading the MS access 2010 solution Office 365 version. I took free trail subscription for Office 365 Enterprise e3 version and i don't see MS Access module in the cloud.

Do i need to do any settings to make it visible in the cloud? Or Office 365 doesn't support MS access in cloud?

If MS access is available in cloud, we would like to have the solution deployed in the cloud so users can work cloud version without installing the Access on their local desktops/Mobile device (Like MS Excel and Word).

Please let me know if this solution is feasible and Office 365 has MS Access in cloud?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is a feasible solution, Your access application can be deployed to SharePoint in Office 365. Where your access app will be hosted in SharePoint as an App. All SharePoint users will be able to run your access app after you publish it to SharePoint.

Here is a link on how to do it step by step:
http://zimmergren.net/technical/building-apps-for-sharepoint-in-office-365-using-access-2013

Hope this helps :)